# Partially unboxed vectors

Tags: haskell, vector, lazy-evaluation

I have a data type of the form:

```
data T = { a :: Int, b :: ComplexOtherDataType }
```

I can obviously put these into regular vectors from the `Data.Vector` module.  But I want really, really good performance when I access the `a` component, so the extra indirection is undesirable.  What I want to do is make `T` an instance of `Data.Vector.Unboxed.Unbox`, but still have `b` be lazy.

The `vector-th-unbox` provides a nice template haskell interface for making instances of `Unbox`, but it won't work in my case.  It requires that in order to make `T` an instance of `Unbox`, both `a` *and* `b` must also be instances.  But I don't want to unbox `b`.  I want it to be boxed/lazy.

My intuition says that the easiest way to overcome this obstacle is by providing a type

```
newtype LazyUnbox a = LazyUnbox a
```

Then, I need to provide an `Unbox` instance for `LazyUnbox` that will basically just store a pointer inside the unboxed vector.  How can I do this?  Or is there a better approach entirely?

Comment: `Storable` vectors have just as good performance and strictness properties as `Unboxed` vectors, so if you can make your datatype `T` implement `Storable` then you are good to go.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How do you imagine "storing a pointer as unbox" (i. e. machine word) value? GHC runtime don't allow to obtain pointers to managed structures, as far as I know.

A tradeoff solution is making your own `VG.Vector` instance, ex.

```
data TVector = TVector (VU.Vector Int) (V.Vector ComplexOtherDataType)

instance VG.Vector TVector T where
    basicUnsafeIndexM (TVector va vb) i = do
        a <- basicUnsafeIndexM va i
        b <- basicUnsafeIndexM vb i
        return (T a b)
    ...
```

You can extract unboxed part `VU.Vector Int` when needed.

Answer (score 4):

Edward Kmett wrote a post explaining how to do this exact thing:
https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/edwardk/revisiting-matrix-multiplication/part-3
I can't understand why the second field stays boxed in his code, but I'm sure that it works. It's the `hybrid-vectors` package.